# How do I use defjump in emacs lisp to jump to a function in a file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

What I'd like that to do, is when I'm on a line of source such as: `<a href="foo.html">foo</a>`

And I hit a "jump" key, it should match `href="foo.html"` and open the file `c:/project/root/templates/foo.html`.

I've found `jump.el` (package 'jump' in emacs 24) and am trying to get `defjump` to work:

```
(require 'jump)
(defjump
  'my-follow-ref
  '(("href=\"\\1\"" . "templates/\\1"))
  "c:/project/root/"
  "Follow a logical link from one part of the source to another.")
```

My code is based on the example in the help, but I'm getting stuck on a pretty basic emacs lisp error:

```
mapcar: Wrong type argument: listp, quote
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `jump.el` in the emacs 24 source tree, and google is no help, but, I guess, your problem is unnecessary quoting: `defjump` is probably a macro.

Chances are this will work:

```
(defjump
  my-follow-ref
  (("href=\"\\1\"" . "templates/\\1"))
  "c:/project/root/"
  "Follow a logical link from one part of the source to another.")
```

Comment: For me, jump.el is just showing up in `list-packages` as "jump", I'm using Emacs Prelude so it could be in another repo?

Comment: You're right, removing the extra quoting has fixed the type error. I'm sure I tried all the permutations of quotes, literals etc., but maybe I didn't do all at once!